# How can I make my Html Helper method make Ajax requests rather than load the entire page in MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have my Alphabetical pager in MVC Partial view:

```
<div class="pagination pagination-left pagination-mini">
     <ul>
        <li>
            @Html.AlphabeticalPager(ViewData["CurrentPage"].ToString(), x => Url.Action("Test", new { page = x }))
        </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

My Controller action:

```
public ActionResult Test(string page)
{
    var items = x => x.Name.StartsWith(page, true, null);
    ViewData["CurrentPage"] = page ?? string.Empty;
    return PartialView(items.ToList());
}
```

My Helper method:

```
public static MvcHtmlString AlphabeticalPager(this HtmlHelper html, string currentPage, Func<string, string> pageUrl)
{
    //code here which creates the list for a page and returns below 
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(result.ToString());
}
```

Currently when I click on a pager example 'A' it loads the partial view in a new window rather than inside the main view which the partial view is in. I want the call/request tobe in Ajax so that the layout remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `jQuery`, you could make a ajax request to the action in the click event (preventing the default functionality) and append the result to the particular `li` element. If you want the pager to be loaded immediately, then make the ajax request in the document ready event.